# MVC PlaceHolder for DDL that disappears**

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, placeholder

I've seen so many posts and examples of people using a DDL placeholder like this...
`@Html.DropDownList("lstUsers",(SelectList)ViewBag.UsersList, "--Select User--")`

or

`@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.RoleID, Model.RoleList, "Select",  new { @id="hi"})`

I mean yea these work, but I want the placeholder to disappear after the ddl index changed, and all these do is place  dummy text for the 1st index which can then be selected again.
I haven't been able to find an answer for the life of me. I've  tried jquery

`$("#tb2").attr("placeholder", "--Please Select--"`

which works for a textbox, but not a DropDown. I'm using dynamically generated ddl's

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the select element works. That "placeholder" is actually a full-fledged option in the select list. It's value is usually set to an empty string so that if it's still selected on POST, an empty string is posted and will caused an error if the field is expected to have a value. It doesn't just disappear automatically on it's own.

A textbox is entirely different. When placeholder text is placed inside a textbox, it is literally overwritten by user input, hence why it goes away. In HTML5 textboxes now have an actual `placeholder` attribute, which will show and hide a bit of text based on the focus of the input. The select element has no equivalent, though.

You could potentially do what you want with some additional JavaScript. You would just watch for a change event on the select and if it has a value (not the "placeholder"), then you could remove the first item from the select (which should be the placeholder):

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        var firstChild = $(this).children().eq(0);
        if (firstChild.prop('value') == '') firstChild.remove();
    }
});
```

*(I'm using jQuery here because doing the same in straight JavaScript would be much more arduous and since you're using ASP.NET MVC, it's a safe bet you're also using jQuery)*

Comment: thank you!! I've been looking for an answer to this on and off for awhile. Now I'd like to figure out how to get this to persist if  `!ModelState.IsValid`. I'm sure its a simple solution im not thinking of

Comment: for anyone using older versions of Jquery you will probably have to use just $('#mySelect').change and attr instead of prop

Comment: You can simply run the same inner bit of script on `$(document).ready`, instead of waiting for a change event.

Comment: yea I looked around that's exactly what I did,  `$(document).ready(function () {
    var isValid = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid))
       $(function () {   if (!isValid) { // insert code} })`... sorry for poor formatting